# GetbyElementID Another Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to set height iframe in another aspx(page) use javascript

this mainframex in body.aspx

```
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <iframe id="mainframex" name="mainframex" class="embed-responsive-item" ramespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0" width="100%" onload="resizeIframe(this)" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

this function in screenMenux.aspx

```
 function resize(frame) {
           var b = frame.contentWindow.document.body || frame.contentDocument.body,
                cHeight = $(b).height();
            if (frame.oHeight !== cHeight) {
                $(frame).height(0);
                frame.style.height = 0;

                $(frame).height(cHeight);
                frame.style.height = cHeight + "px";

                frame.oHeight = cHeight;
                document.getElementById("mainframex").height = cHeight; // id mainframex in body.aspx
            }
```

i use

document.getElementById("mainframex").height = cHeight it's not working

i want change height ifrme body.aspx

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Especially the part with `mainframex` in it.

Comment: ok, here's the code for mainframex
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="row">
                                        <iframe id="mainframex" name="mainframex" class="embed-responsive-item" ramespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0" width="100%" onload="resizeIframe(this)" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

Comment: Please add the code in your question and not in the comments.

Comment: ok.. done......